# How to print variables and values?

Tags: db2

In Sybase, I can use **select** to print, which seems to be unavailable in db2.

```
declare @x int
select "begin"

select 1+1

select @x=1
select @x

select "end"
go
```

How can I do this in db2?

```
BEGIN ATOMIC

declare x int;

set x=1;
-- select "begin"
-- select x;
-- select 1+1;
-- select "end"
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that if you add a FROM clause to your select (you can even create a TEMP TABLE for this purpose, or use an existing one for which you have the SELECT permission). For example: `SELECT 'Hello world' FROM MYTEMPTABLE FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` will produce the expexted result.

From DB2 version 9.7 Oracle PL/SQL syntax can be enabled and "print" statements can be used. Check this article:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0908anonymousblocks/index.html

Answer (score 6):

Additional options are `VALUES (1)` and also selecting from the single-row IBM Dummy Table:

```
 SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```